# What size the data volume of traditional database to choose Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, bigdata

What size the data volume of traditional database to choose Hadoop? What is the basic bench-marked parameter to choose Hadoop system over traditional database?

Comment: Hadoop is not a database.

Comment: I suggest you to read this topic: http://superuser.com/questions/1158843/why-is-hadoop-not-a-data-warehouse/1163323#1163323

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific "size" to move from RDBMS to Hadoop. Two things to know:

1. They are very different.(read on to know more)
2. The size of data that RDBMS can handle is dependent on the capability of the DataBase Server.

---

Traditional databases are **RDBMS**(Relational Database Management System) where we insert data as rows, which get stored in the database. You may **Alter/Query/Update the database**.

**Hadoop** is a framework for storage and processing data(large amounts of data). It has two parts: **Storage**(Hadoop Distributed File System) and **MapReduce**(processing framework).

Hadoop stores data as files on its FS. So if you want to Update/alter/query it like RDBMS its not possible.
We do have SQL wrappers over Hadoop like Hive or impala but they aren't as performant as RDBMS on data(not big data).

Even with all this many are considering moving from RDBMS to Hadoop because RDBMS under-performs with large data(bigdata). **Hadoop can be used as a DataStore and Queries over it could be run using Hive/Impala. Updates are not readily supported on Hadoop.**

There are many pros and cons of using Hadoop over RDBMS. Read more.. [here](http://www.wikidifference.com/difference-between-hadoop-and-rdbms/) or[here](https://www.qubole.com/blog/big-data/hadoop-vs-traditional/)